# Properties on conditional demand correspondence from the textbook of Mas-Colell et al

Tags: microeconomics, self-study, producer-theory, mwg

I have a question on the properties of conditional demand correspondence

Let $z(w,q)$ be the **conditional factor demand correspondence**, i.e. the solution of the cost minimization problem

\begin{align}
\min_z \quad& w\cdot z \\ \text{subject to}\quad & f(z)\geq q.
\end{align}

In the book of Mas-Colell, Whinston, Green, Proposition 5.C.2 (v) says that

> if the set $\{z\ge 0 : f(z)\ge q\} $ is convex then $z(w,q) $ is a convex set.

Also, in the same property, it states that

> if $f$ is quasiconcave then $z(w,q)$ is a convex set for every $w>>0$.

How can I prove these two statements? I would like to understand these two properties. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which edition of MWG are you using? I do not see that statement in Proposition 5.B.2 in my edition.

Comment: @hrrrrrr5602 1995, page 141

Comment: Okay, you mean 5.C.2?

Comment: Can you show us your calculations? You mean the set $\{z \leq 0: f(z) \geq q\}$ ? If there are two elements in this convex set, then any linear combination of these two elements are also in this set. Does it also minimize cost?

Comment: @hrrrrrr5602 Yes you are right! Sorry for my typo..

Comment: MWG states $z \ge 0, f(z) \ge q$, which makes more sense. Also, I do not see the second statement you wrote above in Proposition 5.C.2.

Comment: The book is by Mas-Colell, Whinston, and Green, not by someone called Colell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $z_1$ and $z_2$ be $\geq 0$ and solution to

$$\min_z \{w^\top z\lvert f(z)\geq q\}$$

then clearly $f(z_1)\geq q$ and $f(z_2)\geq q$ and since $\{z\geq 0\lvert f(z)\geq z \}$ is convex it then follows that $z_3 := \lambda z_1 + (1-\lambda)z_2$ must satisfy the constraint $f(z_3)\geq q$.

Since $z_1$ and $z_2$ are both minimizers it cannot be the case that $w^\top z_1 \not = w^\top z_2$ rather it must be the case that $w^\top z_1 = w^\top z_2$. This implies that $w^\top z_3 = w^\top(\lambda z_1 + (1-\lambda)z_2) = \lambda w^\top z_1 + (1-\lambda) w^\top z_2 = w^\top z_1$ hence $z_3$ is a minimizer.

Since $z_3$ is minimizer and satisfy constraint it must be in $z(w,q)$ which therefore must be convex set.

If $f$ is quasi concave then by definition $\{z\geq 0 \lvert f(z) \geq q\}$ is convex and therefore using the above argument implies $z(w,q)$ is convex.